# Chrome Driver issue in Lambda function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I am using below code in AWS Lambda Function

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('--start-fullscreen')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver', options=options)
```

**Error:**

> [ERROR] WebDriverException: **Message: Service /opt/chromedriver
> unexpectedly exited.** Status code was: 127
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 27, in lambda_handler
>     **driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver', options=options)**   File
> "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
> line 70, in **init**
>     super(WebDriver, self).**init**(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
>   File
> "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py",
> line 90, in **init**
>     self.service.start()   File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 98, in start
>     self.assert_process_still_running()   File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 110, in assert_process_still_running

**Note :** My Layer structure is below in zip file and using curl command to get linux drivers for lambda

```
curl -SL https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_linux64.zip > chromedriver.zip
curl -SL https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/releases/download/v1.0.0-41/stable-headless-chromium-amazonlinux-2017-03.zip > headless-chromium.zip
```

[image]

Comment: If it is `--headless`, then there is no point in `--start-maximized` and `--start-fullscreen`.  I don't know whether Chrome validates its parameters that far, but it's possible.  I suggest you remove the two `--start-*` parameters.

Comment: I have removed both. But still same issue, I think python3.8 has some compatibility issue with curl command which I am using to get chrome driver and binary. Can you please suggest @TimRoberts

Comment: What happens if you run `/opt/headless-chromium` from a command line?

Comment: Is it possible to run it from command line? I was using Lambda console to run python code.

Comment: @TimRoberts Do you have any suggestion for me ? I am not getting compatibility documents from anywhere and I am not sure /opt/ path is correct or not.

Comment: It's possible those files are not executable.  You should try doing `chmod +x` on both of them, or from Python `os.chmod( "/opt/headless-chromium", 0755)`.

Comment: While executing 2nd command , I am getting new error as :: "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/opt/chromedriver'", @TimRoberts

Comment: I don't know how you configure a lamba.  Perhaps you have to do the `chmod` when you create the package you send over.

Comment: I used python3.7 with different chrome and selenium versions and It worked.. Thank you @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used python3.7 and used zip package which is available in below link

[Working layer for me](https://github.com/soumilshah1995/Selenium-on-AWS-Lambda-Python3.7)